# Chrome vertical-align in Quirks and Standards modes

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, quirks-mode

The following images are the rendering for the same page using the same browser (Chrome 25). The only difference is one page have a DOCTYPE (thus in Standars mode) and one doesn't (thus in Quirks)

Quirks:
[image]
Standards:
[image]

Both cells have `vertical-align: middle`, both images are `display: inline-block`.
Vertical-align is working in Quirks but not in Standards, why?

---

HTML

```
<table class="oppres" id="oppscore4">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="oppscore4-main">
            <td><img src="images/gold.png"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr id="oppscore4-total">
            <td></td>
            <td>=</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table.oppres{
    height: 120px;
}

table[id^=oppscore]{
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1;
}
table[id^=oppscore] tr{height: 1em;}
table[id^=oppscore] img{height: 0.9em;}
table[id^=oppscore] tr:nth-last-child(2){height: auto;}
table[id^=oppscore] td:first-child{text-align: right;}
```

More than enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: The picture in quirks looks cropped compared to standards. Standards is showing it correctly, likely, and quirks is not (the nature of quirks). Without code it is very difficult to speculate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not about `vertical-align` on `<td>` but on `<img />`

Quirks mode triggers a behaviour explained [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html):

> Vertical alignment of an image is under certain conditions to the bottom of the enclosing box, not to the baseline of text. This happens when the image is the only content within an element, typically a table cell. This means that e.g. an image in a table cell is by default at the bottom of the cell in Quirks Mode (which is often what the author wants), whereas in Standards Mode there is a few pixels spacing below the image (unless one sets e.g. vertical-align: bottom for the img element).

The space you see in standard mode below the image is actually the space between the `<td>`'s box baseline and bottom (cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading).

When `vertical-align` is `bottom` on `<img />` its box' bottom is aligned with `<td>`'s box bottom, so there is no space anymore.

Comment: I want the image to be middle-aligned (vertically) and `vertical-align: middle` on the image doesn't work.

Comment: It's because the line-height doesn't let enough space. Try to remove it.

Comment: Rather align bottom or top than changing the line-height. Doesn't look that bad anyways. Seems problem solved

Comment: Your question was "Vertical-align is working in Quirks but not in Standards, why?", consider accepting my answer, thanks.